# .htaccess redirect all requests to one page and ADD www if missing

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to direct a ceraitin request to a specif page and then a catch all for all others. Whilst also applying the rule of adding www to the begining of the URL. I have tried multiple solutions, all to no avail.

Here is my latest attempt. The browser displays a 500 misconfiguration message.

```
# Add www to domain 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# target without trailing slash 
RewriteRule ^myWord$ /myWordFolder/index.php [L]

# target with trailing slash 
RewriteRule ^myWord/$ /myWordFolder/index.php [L]

# catch all non myWord requests
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /catchAllFolder/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe last rule need to have an extra condition to stop rewriting for `/catchAllFolder/` requests.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Add www to domain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# target with/without trailing slash 
RewriteRule ^myWord/?$ /myWordFolder/index.php [L]

# catch all non myWord requests
RewriteRule !^catchAllFolder/ /catchAllFolder/ [NC,L]
```